# Django view templates filter database

Tags: python, sql, django, templates, filter

Whats is the best approach to filter context. I want to view on my index page last three objects from Roslina and related to them all Images with the same nazwa_polska(foreign_key)

```
my model.py
**class Roslina(models.Model):
    id_rosliny = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nazwa_polska = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    nazwa_lacinska = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    opis = models.TextField()
    data = models.DateField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa_polska
class Images(models.Model):
    nazwa_polska = models.ForeignKey(Roslina, related_name='image', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=generate_filename);
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa_polska.nazwa_polska**
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView,TemplateView
from . import models
# Create your views here.
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name='index.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['zdjecia'] = models.Images.objects.all()
         context['rosliny'] = models.Roslina.objects.all()
         return context
class WyborAtlasu(TemplateView):
    template_name='basic_app/wyborAtlasu.html'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to view on my index page last three objects from Roslina

"last" according to which criteria ? But anyway, the solution is to [sort your queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) on the desired field(s) - using a descendant sort to get the "last" records first (reverse sort) - then [slice it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) to get the first three records. This is better done in the view itself.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    last_rosliny =  models.Roslina.objects.order_by("-date")[:3]
    context['rosliny'] = last_rosliny
    # you don't need this one, cf below
    # context['zdjecia'] = models.Images.objects.all()
    return context
```

> and related to them all Images with the same nazwa_polska(foreign_key)

Given your models definition, you can get a `Roslina`'s related images through it's "image" related descriptor (in your case it is named "image" because you explicitely named it so: `models.ForeignKey(Roslina, related_name='image'...)` - `images` would have been a better name but anyway), ie:

```
r = Roslina.objects.get(id_rosliny=<id_of_a_rosliny_here>)
for image in r.image.all():
    print(image.pk, image.image)
```

Now since Django template language allow for attribute lookup and method calls (for methods that don't take any parameter at least) you don't need to add images to your view's context, you can access them from the `Roslina` directly in the template:

```
# yourtemplate.html 
<ul>
  {% for roslina in rosliny %}
  <li>
    {{ roslina.nazwa_polska }}
    <ul>
      {% for image in roslina.image.all %}
      <li>{{ image.pk }} - {{ image.image.url }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

PS : hope I got the singular / plural forms right, sorry but I'm afraid I don't speak your language ;)

Comment: Glad I could help - and if that's the case feel free to upvote and accept the answer ;)